# When can I use the Chió pivotal condensation?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I've found this site: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChioPivotalCondensation.html

And there is the $a_{ii} \neq 0$ condition. Is it really necessary for all of the numbers in the main diagonal to be non-zero? I've tested it on a small matrix, with 1 zero element, and I've got the right answer (or I've got it because I miscounted something?).

Comment: It suffices that $a_{11} \neq 0$; you don't need the other diagonal entries to be nonzero.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks!